How to set the "Transfer-Encoding" header in the python requests library?
I am using the python requests library and want to send a request with the header "Transfer-Encoding:chunked".
Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work.
Even if I explicitely set the header, it is not used in the request.
Below is my code for testing and the corresponding captured request:
import requests

url = 'http://[replaced]/test.php'

def data_chunks():
    yield b'8\r\n'
    yield b'search=1\r\n'
    yield b'0\r\n'

response = requests.post(url,data=data_chunks(), headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked"}, proxies={"http":"http://127.0.0.1:8080"})


POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: [replaced]
User-Agent: python-requests/2.28.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: /
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 16
8
search=1
0

If I do not set the "Transfer-Encoding" header it is not used and even if I explicitly set the "Transfer-Encoding" header like in the example above it is not used. 
The requests library always seems to put a "Content-Length" instead. 
What am I supposed to do?
UPDATE
If I build a request from scratch (including "Transfer-Encoding:chunked") and send it with a tool like Burp, I get the server responds I am looking for. However, it seems like the requests library is not capable of doing it or it is really well hidden. This is unfortunate as I wanted to automate some testing.

Have you tried the method described in the docs: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests

Yes that is how I started my journey ...

You don't REQUEST Transfer-Encoding: chunked.  That's a RESPONSE field, sent when the server has decided the data needs to be chunked.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding

As far as I am aware, chunked encoding can be used in requests (https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling) - "Browsers do not normally use chunked encoding in requests, and it is normally seen only in server responses."
